# Figures and figure caption side-by-side in RMarkdown Beamer

Tags: latex, r-markdown, figure, caption, beamer

[image]

[image]

The plot in from [http://xkcd.com/1132，and](http://xkcd.com/1132%EF%BC%8Cand) I just want one slide is figure caption beside the figure.

[image]

````
---
title: "CH6 Testing"
date: ""
fontsize: 9pt
header-includes:
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}
 \usepackage{xeCJK}
 \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle] ##可以改變符號的形狀
output:
 beamer_presentation:
  latex_engine: xelatex
---


## 6.10 The local FDR



```{r,echo=F,out.width='40%',fig.cap='While the frequentist only has the currently available data, the Bayesian can draw on her understanding of the world or on previous experience. As a Bayesian, she would know enough about physics to understand that our sun’s mass is too small to become a nova. Even if she does not know physics, she might be an empirical Bayesian and draw her prior from a myriad previous days where the sun did not go nova.',fig.margin=F,fig.align='center'}
knitr::include_graphics("./frequentists_vs_bayesians.png")
```
````

Comment: sorry, the link is  http://xkcd.com/1132

Comment: Please consider [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: @Boyan Please add you code as text

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the code is just what I show

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz My question is just can I set the fig.cap beside the figure?

Comment: Your code is just and image which we can't copy. Please add it as TEXT.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz oh, it's okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `\captionof` macro from the `caption` package to place the caption in a column besides the image:

```
---
title: "CH6 Testing"
date: ""
fontsize: 9pt
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{color}
 - \usepackage{pdfpages}
 - \usepackage{xeCJK}
 - \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle] 
 - \usepackage{caption}
output:
 beamer_presentation:
  latex_engine: xelatex
---


## 6.10 The local FDR

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.55\textwidth}
\captionof{figure}{While the frequentist only has the currently available data, the Bayesian can draw on her understanding of the world or on previous experience. As a Bayesian, she would know enough about physics to understand that our sun’s mass is too small to become a nova. Even if she does not know physics, she might be an empirical Bayesian and draw her prior from a myriad previous days where the sun did not go nova.}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
```

[image]

Comment: But I got error when I use the caption packages.

The error message:
錯誤發生在 yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE)：
  Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1 did not find expected key at line 9, column 2
呼叫： <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
停止執行

Comment: Did you try with the exact same code as in my answer or your actual document?

Comment: Sorry,it can work.

Comment: so i just change \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}

example-image-duck ,right?

Comment: @Boyan Yes, replace `example-image-duck` with the name of your image

Comment: I appreciate your help very much.